# MYSQL - Fetch proper cashback value

Tags: php, mysql

I have 1 mysql table containing following values.

```
When pass value as 5, it should return cashback_vaule = 1
because passed value within 1-10 range & its cashback_vaule is 1
```

and

```
When pass value as 25, it should return cashback_vaule = 3
because passed value within 21-30 range & its cashback_vaule is = 3
```

and

```
When pass value more than 30, it should return cashback_vaule = 3
because max cashback_vaule is = 3
```

I need to make query to fetch cashback_vaule accordingly.

```
tbl_cashback

-------------------------------------------------------------
id  cashback_range_from cashback_range_to   cashback_vaule(%)
-------------------------------------------------------------
1   1                   10                   1
2   11                  20                   2
3   21                  30                   3
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
$your_value = "5";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_cashback 
        WHERE '$your_value'>=cashback_range_from
        AND '$your_value'<=cashback_range_to ";
```

Comment: Not working....

SELECT * FROM tbl_cashback WHERE cashback_range_from >='5' AND cashback_range_to <='5'
 
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0003 sec)

Comment: When i am trying to pass input value greater than max i.e. 30 its not returning result...

otherwise it will be ok

Comment: yes because there is no range greater than 30 in you table

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT cashback_vaule FROM tbl_cashback 
     WHERE cashback_range_from>=input AND cashback_range_to<=input
```